# How to Copy highlighted text to richtext box editor by adding Quote Tags using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am developing a forum website using ASP.net and in there when a user try to give a reply to already wrote post he can quote specific parts of that post.

I saw this quote thing on asp.net forum
https://forums.asp.net

[image]

In there you can highlight texts and when you click the quote button the highlighted text will be display in below tinymce richtext editor. I have the same implementation.

But I am not a expert in javascript. So far I achieved was this

```
<script>
    function handlePaste(e) {
        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        // Stop data actually being pasted into div
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
        clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

        // Do whatever with pasteddata
        alert(pastedData);
    }

    document.getElementById('reference-post-content').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
</script>
```

In there if highlighted a text and press CTRL+C and then again if i press CTRL+V then it will give a popup message by displaying that highlighted text. But this is not what i wanted.
What I want is that text should go to richtextbox below if user click quote btn. Also it should go to rich textbox like this.

```
[quote user="ksss"]

message is in a thread in which the user is a THREAD_PARTICIPANT.

I'm afraid I can never state these

[/quote]
```

So how to do this? Here I found this javascript code by doing a browser debug on asp.net forums by using chrome. But it seems not working.

```
<script>
    $("#quote-action") != null && $("#quote-action").bind("click", function () {
        var n = null, t = $("#quote-createdby").val();
        if (window.getSelection && (window.getSelection() || window.getSelection().extentNode != null) && window.getSelection().rangeCount > 0) {
            var i = window.getSelection(), u = i.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents(), r = document.createElement("div"); r.appendChild(u); n = r.innerHTML; i.removeAllRanges()
        }
        else document.selection && (n = document.selection.createRange().htmlText, document.selection.empty()); (n == null || n == "") && (n = $("#reference-post-content").html());
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "/soa/post/body/removeprettyprinttags", data: { body: n }, success: function (i) { i != null && i.result != "" && (n = i.result); tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus(); tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(tinyMCE.activeEditor.updatedSelectionBookmark); tinyMCE.execCommand("mceInsertContent", !1, '[quote user="' + t + '"]' + n + "[/quote]"); UpdateBookmark(tinyMCE.activeEditor) }, error: function (i, r, u) { isProd || alert("Error: " + r + " " + u); tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus(); tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(tinyMCE.activeEditor.updatedSelectionBookmark); tinyMCE.execCommand("mceInsertContent", !1, '[quote user="' + t + '"]' + n + "[/quote]"); UpdateBookmark(tinyMCE.activeEditor) } })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Something like... $('.richTextBox).val('[quote user="ksss"]' + pastedData + '[/quote])

Comment: hi @dmoo can you please paste the full cord as a reply. I am learner to these things, thanks